# SQL query is not working near the third AND

Tags: php, mysql

I cant find why my code in sublime, aint beeing taken. Here is the picture how it looks like: [image]

As you can see third AND is losing meaning. And i think it doesnt work. How can i solve this problem, here is the full query:

```
$number = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*), task_type FROM dotp_tasks WHERE (task_type = '$key') AND (task_project in (". join(',',$with_type) .")) AND (task_id in (" . join(',',$UsrTasks) . "))");
```

Comment: I count more closing parentheses than opening ones. Although, seeing as they're all ANDs, I'm not sure why you need and parentheses at all.

Comment: @Strawberry you count it in picture? COuse full code is bellow the picture.

Comment: Also, you appear to be missing a GROUP BY clause or, rather, the task_type column in the SELECT clause is redundant because we already know what the task_type is

Comment: if the problem is the highlighting, change your IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$UsrTasks` contains integers and `$with_type` contains strings you need to add proper `'`s. All `()` not needed in this case. The query should be -

```
"SELECT COUNT(*), task_type 
FROM dotp_tasks 
WHERE task_type = '$key' 
AND task_project in ('". join("','", $with_type) ."')
AND task_id in (" . join(',',$UsrTasks) . ")"
```

Comment: pls explain why () removed and what effect it causes on Query.

Comment: Print the query in PHP and then check.